# Is it possible to get full data on every golf round played by pro?

Tags: statistics, golf

For example, is there a place to find scores (total strokes + amount under or over par) for every round a golfer has played as part of a pro tournament?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of global site but you can search it for specific rounds for example: http://www.europeantour.com/europeantour/stats/genworthfs/, http://www.cbssports.com/golf/stats, http://www.golfstat.com/

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! This is a source/research request and not constructive for our site per our [FAQ](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for scores within the last 10 years for the PGA, [ESPN.com](http://espn.go.com/golf/statistics)'s golf page has information dating back to 2003. If you select a year and a golfer, you can view their individual profile, and scorecards can be seen under the *Scorecards* tab.